# Stopping EXIM on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exim

I have EXIM running on a server that I am trying to decommission (but I still have stuff I need to move off).

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 stop

* Stopping MTA                                                          [ OK ]
* ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size,
            mail system possibly broken
```

2011-02-01 19:18:37 string too large in smtp_notquit_exit()

How can I stop exim from running and accepting mail on port 25?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo pgrep exim | xargs kill -9` # will kill all processes that contain exim string

`sudo dpkg --purge exim4` # to uninstall exim4

Comment: I found I needed "sudo pgrep exim | sudo xargs kill -9"

Answer (score 2):

Either of these should work:

```
sudo killall -9 exim
```

or

```
sudo pkill -9 exim
```

To purge, try `sudo apt-get purge exim4*` .

This will also remove `exim4-base* exim4-config* exim4-daemon-light*`